# jQuery.jGrowl Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: php, jquery

I know that this question have been asked before but I still couldn't find the solution for my problem.. The thing is.. it happens at production server, but works well in development. So I'm not sure whats wrong with it.
Appreciate if you could advice.
Thanks in advance.

The following is my code.. and I had this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error on my jQuery.jGrowl

```html
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jquery.jgrowl.css">
<?php $message  = $_SESSION['message'];
  if($message) { ?>
    <script>
      jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.jGrowl("<?php echo $message; ?>", { header: 'Message' });
      });
    </script>
    <?php $_SESSION['message'] = '';
  }
?>
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

On this line:

```
jQuery.jGrowl("<?php echo $message; ?>", { header: 'Message' });
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `$message` PHP variable contains a double quote or newline which is breaking your string. Can you show us the actual output instead of the PHP spaghetti

Comment: Inside `$message` might be an `"` or `\n` char

Comment: Yes, in $message contain quotes.. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `$message` string contains chars, which breaks the string. This could be a `"` or `\n` char. You could fix this by usig an escape function.

`json_encode` should be sufficient

```
jQuery.jGrowl(<?php echo json_encode($message); ?>, { header: 'Message' });
```

Note, that i removed the `"` around the string.

Comment: Ok.. I will try this solution.. will update the result.. one moment

Comment: I've tried.. but still get the error.. value in $message is $_SESSION['message'] = 'Input File NOT OK '.$_FILES['inputFile']['name'].'"'; Should I remove the quotes at the end?